# How to run jumpTo(n) slider in mobile view owl-carusel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I`m using owl-carousel for slider, what I want is to jump to the third image in mobile view, how should do that?

[owl-slider](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/index.html#customizing)

This is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    autoPlay: true, // Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
    items: 5,
    itemsDesktop: [1199, 3],
    itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 3],
    itemsMobile: [479, 1]    
  });
})
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    autoPlay: true, // Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
    items: 5,
    itemsDesktop: [1199, 3],
    itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 3],
    itemsMobile: [479, 1]    
  });

  var owl = $("#owl-demo");
  owl.jumpTo(x) //x= some number
})
```

[NICE CODEPEN  EXAMPLE HERE](http://codepen.io/OwlFonk/pen/zukol)